# Include a Verilog Header file using a Do file for Modelsim

Tags: verilog, simulation, header-files, system-verilog, modelsim

In a system-verilog file that I was given is an `include` for a Verilog Header file (`.vh`). When I manually run a simulation in Modelsim I usually go into the properties of the file ("Verilog & SystemVerilog" tab) and include the directory that holds the header file there. How would I go about making reference to it in a `.do` file that I am trying to create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a file included with the `include macro; you should be able to use the `+incdir+<path>` argument to the compile command; where path is the path to the directory containing the `.vh` or `.svh` file(s).